How to Parse Large Excel Sheets in javascript
I need to parse large excel sheet of size upto 5GM but getting this error
Error parsing XLSX: RangeError: Invalid string length
at Array.join (<anonymous>)
at concat (C:\Users\Pie-Cyfer\Desktop\CPE_BE\node_modules\jszip\lib\stream\StreamHelper.js:53:26)
at StreamHelper.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Pie-Cyfer\Desktop\CPE_BE\node_modules\jszip\lib\stream\StreamHelper.js:98:65)
at Immediate.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Pie-Cyfer\Desktop\CPE_BE\node_modules\jszip\lib\utils.js:406:18)
at processImmediate (node:internal/timers:478:21)

Can anyone suggest a library than can parse excel sheet of size upto 5GM ?
I have tried ExcelJS,xlsx-parse-stream and SheetJS but nothing works
const stream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
  const workbook = new ExcelJS.Workbook();

  await workbook.xlsx.read(stream);

  const worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet(1);

  const dataRows: any[][] = [];
  let isFirstRow = true;

  worksheet.eachRow({ includeEmpty: true }, (row) => {
    const rowValues = Array.isArray(row.values) ? row.values.slice(1) : [];

    const parsedRowValues = rowValues.map(value => {
      if (typeof value === 'object' && value !== null) {
        if (value instanceof Date) {
          return parseDate(value.toISOString());
        } 
      }
      console.log(value, typeof value)
      return value;
    });

    if (isFirstRow) {
      columns = parsedRowValues.map(header => header ? header.toString().trim() : '');
      console.log(columns, typeof columns);
      isFirstRow = false;
    } else {
      dataRows.push(parsedRowValues);
    }
  });


Please edit your question to include code and error messages as text.

Side note: with that much data, Excel is probably the wrong tool to use.

I recommend you export the Excel file to CSV. So it can be parsed easily as plain text.
Then use Node.js fs.createReadStream to process one line at a time and avoid loading the entire file in memory:
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');

// Create a readable stream
const fileStream = fs.createReadStream('path/to/your/largefile.csv');

// Create a readline interface
const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: fileStream,
  crlfDelay: Infinity
});

// Event listener for each line
rl.on('line', (line) => {
  const columns = line.split(',');
  console.log('Row:', columns);
  console.log('First column:', columns[0]);
});

// Event listener for when reading is complete
rl.on('close', () => {
  console.log('CSV file processing complete.');
});

